# JEditor not displaying the HTML page as in IE of Firefox..?

Tags: java, html, swing

I am using JEditor to display HTML pages. The issue is that JEditor is not displaying the pages as they are displayed in IE or Firefox. Major issue is with Paragraph Tag. JEditor is not giving the
paragraph effect, instead its working like a simple Line break 
 tag.

UPDATED - The paragraph tag used is `<p>....</p>`

Comment: *"The issue is that JEditor is not displaying the pages as they are displayed in IE or Firefox."*  JEditorPane is not a browser. I would not expect it to render like one.  *"Major issue is with Paragraph Tag."*  What paragraph tag?  Or more specifically, where is your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading HTML file to view in JEditorPane](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569351/reading-html-file-to-view-in-jeditorpane)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JEditor is based on javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit, which according to its [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLEditorKit.html)  it only supports HTML 3.2 and most likely minimal CSS. You can't expect it to work like any current browser.

If you need to display "modern" HTML/CSS in your application, you'll need to embed a browser in it (which isn't trivial): https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java+swing+embed+browser&submit=search